# Help with order of quantifiers

Tags: quantifiers

I have to say if the following are true or false and why. Can someone check to see if I understand how orders of quantifiers affect the meaning?

1. For every integer x, there exists an integer y such that y>x. 
   True. Whatever integer x is, there will be a bigger y.
2. There exists an integer x such that for every integer y, y>x. 
   False. If x is a specific integer, there's a possibility that a y is smaller.
3. For every integer x and y, y>x.
   False. There's a possibility that the x>y.
4. There exists an x and y such that y>x.
   True. It is possible that for one chosen x, there is a y that is larger.

Thank you!

Comment: looks all good to me

Comment: All your answers are correct.

Comment: Yes you are ok. .Always apply some common sense to mathematical sentences.

Comment: A comment on #4: a completely correct answer is "True: $2>1$." A purely existential statement requires only a single example to verify. While your answer to #4 is arguably correct, I believe that "$2>1$" is clearer, in that it communicates better the understanding that an example suffices in that case.